# No consigo guardar imágenes con move_uploaded_file()

Tags: php

Buenas,

Tengo un formulario donde entre otros inputs, tengo uno del tipo "file" para poder subir imágenes. Después quisiera guardar esas imágenes en la carpeta de mi proyecto.

```
<form class="articulos" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="nuevo_post.php" method="post">

        <h1>Título</h1>
        <input type="text" name="titulo"  placehoder="Introduce el título del artículo">

        <h1>Publicado por:</h1>
        <select class="select" name="creador">
            <option name="Egoi" value="Egoi" <?php if ($creador == 'Egoi Cantero') {echo 'selected';} ?>>Egoi Cantero</option>
        </select>

        <h1>Categoria:</h1>
        <select class="select" name="categoria">
            <option name="Articulo" value="Articulo" <?php if ($categoria == 'Articulo') {echo 'selected';} ?>>Articulo</option>
            <option name="Analisis" value="Analisis" <?php if ($categoria == 'Analisis') {echo 'selected';} ?>>Análisis</option>
        </select>

        <h1>Artículo</h1>
        <textarea name="articulo"></textarea>

        <input class="fichero" type="file" name="thumb">

        <input class="enviar" type="submit" name="enviar" value="Crear nuevo post">
    </form>
```

La parte de PHP, tengo lo siguiente:

```
$thumb = $_FILES['thumb']['tmp_name'];
$thumb_db = $_FILES['thumb']['name'];

$ruta = '../imagenes/articulos/' . $thumb_db;

move_uploaded_file($thumb, $ruta);
```

La carpeta la tengo creada ya en el directorio, pero me muestra 2 errores:

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(../imagenes/articulos/image-12.jpeg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/xboxone/admin/nuevo_post.php on line 29
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/phpzypxGa' to '../imagenes/articulos/image-12.jpeg' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/xboxone/admin/nuevo_post.php on line 29

Podría guardarlas manualmente en la carpeta y dado que estoy guardando el nombre de la imagen en la base de datos cargarla con PHP, pero de esta forma me olvido de guardar el fichero.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2):

Resuelto, el código es correcto. El problema lo tenía con los permisos de la carpeta, que sólo tenía derechos de lectura. Hay que habilitar derechos de escritura también.